# Resetting the ID in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am working on the MYSQL database which originally had the id's auto-incremented from 00001. But for some reason, we changed reset those to 2000, now the client wants to reset those again back to 00001. I tried the following :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=00001
```

In the SQL part of phpmyadmin, I have also tried these steps :

1) select the table
2) goto Operations
3) goto Table Options
4) change the auto increment value

in both the ways, I am not able to reset the value.

Comment: If you have data in the table you cannot simply reset the auto_increment value see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html in particular the section InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT Counter Initialization and the sentence To initialize an auto-increment counter after a server restart, InnoDB executes the equivalent of the following statement on the first insert into a table containing an AUTO_INCREMENT column.


SELECT MAX(ai_col) FROM table_name FOR UPDATE;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done via phpMyAdmin:

- On your id column, remove the auto-increment setting
- Delete your primary key in Structure > indexes
- Create a new column future_id as primary key, auto_increment
- Browse your table and verify that the new increments correspond to what you're expecting
- Drop your old id column
- Rename the future_id column to id
- Move the new id column via Structure > Move columns